# How to add text overlay effect on hover using CSS with text?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to add an overlay effect to all images, with text overlaying the image. I tried tutorials but could not get it to work. All the images are located in main.js.

```js
const petsData = [{
    name: "Purrsloud",
    species: "Cat",
    favFoods: ["wet food", "dry food", "<strong>any</strong> food"],
    birthYear: 2016,
    brick: "brick",
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Barksalot",
    species: "Dog",
    birthYear: 2008,
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/dog-1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Meowsalot",
    species: "Cat",
    favFoods: ["tuna", "catnip", "celery"],
    birthYear: 2012,
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-1.jpg"
  }
];





function petTemplate(pet) {
  return `
              <div class="animal">
              
             <img class="pet-photo" src="${pet.photo}"> 
              <h2 class="pet-name">${pet.name} <span class="species">(${pet.species})</span></h2>
        
              </div>
            `;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
            <h1 class="app-title">Pets (${petsData.length} results)</h1>
            ${petsData.map(petTemplate).join("")}
    
          `;
```

```css
.img {
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.app-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
}

.animal {
  max-width: 650px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animal h4 {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}

.pet-photo {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all linear 0.7s;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.pet-name {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.species {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #888;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Thank you.

Edit - Want it to look something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exb2ab72Xhs&t=475s need to show the text on hover with a black overlay appearing on the back of the text (when hovered on)

Comment: "I could not get it to work" what does "work" mean here? How do you want it to look like?

Comment: Hi Luis!, quick question: What do you mean with overlay? could you upload an image to visualize what you want?

Comment: Just position your pet-name over the image, add something like `.pet-name{ position: aboslute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div that will overlay the image, and populate it with the petsData information. Style that overlay div as `position:absolute` and set the `top`, `width` and `z-index` values appropriately.

Note that in order for `position:absolute` to work on the overlay div, the parent div must be styled as `position: relative` (or `absolute` - anything except the default, which is `static`)

```js
const petsData = [{
    name: "Purrsloud",
    species: "Cat",
    favFoods: ["wet food", "dry food", "<strong>any</strong> food"],
    birthYear: 2016,
    brick: "brick",
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Barksalot",
    species: "Dog",
    birthYear: 2008,
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/dog-1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Meowsalot",
    species: "Cat",
    favFoods: ["tuna", "catnip", "celery"],
    birthYear: 2012,
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-1.jpg"
  }
];





function petTemplate(pet) {
  return `
     <div class="animal">
        <img class="pet-photo" src="${pet.photo}"> 
        <h2 class="pet-name">${pet.name} <span class="species">(${pet.species})</span></h2>
        <div class="olay">
            <div>Name: ${pet.name}</div>
            <div>Type: ${pet.species}</div>
            <div>Favs: ${pet.favFoods !== undefined ? pet.favFoods : ''}</div>
            <div>Born: ${pet.birthYear}</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
     <h1 class="app-title">Pets (${petsData.length} results)</h1>
     ${petsData.map(petTemplate).join("")}
  `;
```

```css
.img {
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.app-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
}

.animal {
  max-width: 650px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animal h4 {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}

.pet-photo {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all linear 0.7s;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.pet-name {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.species {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #888;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/*  ADDED  */
.animal{position:relative;}
.olay{
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you this works but how do i get a black background behind it when o hover on it?

Comment: Thank you for the tips ill keep that in mind the next time. I figured it out somehow works nicely,